# Can getMouse act on one specific object in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.3, zelle-graphics

I am trying to make a Tic Tac Toe game in Python using the Zellegraphics module. I want to use `getMouse` for mouse input but I am unable to figure out how to make `getMouse` to work on one cell of the board. I defined 9 different squares and what I want to do is that if the user clicks on one certain square, I want to draw the X or the O there. I can't figure out how to do that, because as far as I know, `getMouse` only acts on the whole window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some X and Y coordinates in the window (let's call them, say, `window_x` and `window_y`) and you want to get the coordinates on a grid (let's call them `grid_x`, and`grid_y`), and each grid cell has a width and height of `grid_size`, it is relatively easy to calculate `grid_x` and `grid_y`: simply integer divide (round down; in Python, that would be the `//` operator) `window_x` by `grid_size` to get `grid_x`. You can probably figure out `grid_y`.

[image: A 3x3 grid is labeled with (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0) on the first row, (0, 1), (1, 1), and (2, 1) on the second row, and so on. The width of a cell is labeled grid_size. A particular point is labeled as a red dot. The X and Y location of the point are labeled from the top left corner of the grid.]

Comment: Okay. I am still pretty confused. Could you explain a little more please?

Comment: Use `getMouse` to retrieve `window_x` and `window_y`. Calculate `grid_x` as `window_x // grid_size` and `grid_y` similarly. `grid_x` and `grid_y` are the coordinates of the cell on the grid that the user clicked.

Comment: But the think is, I don't know how to use getMouse to retrieve window_x and window_y. I get the rest though.

Comment: [`getMouse`](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/node2.html#47) returns a [`Point`](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/node4.html). Use `getX` and `getY` on that point to get `window_x` and `window_y`. Your code would look like: `point = window.getMouse(); window_x, window_y = point.getX(), point.getY()`